# Java Unsupported major.minor version 49.0 - where is it coming from?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, zxing

I have downloaded the zxing Google QR code from SVN and used eclipse to edit one of the class files.

I've compiled the changes using ANT and it runs fine locally. When I run it on alive server I get an error:

```
500 com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
```

I have tried compiling it in JDK 1.6 and 1.5 and I get the same error message. Is this something to do with editing the class file in eclipse, and eclipse saving it using a different JVM?

Live server is running 6.0.150

Comment: Which jre is the live server running?  It sounds like it's probably 1.4, which means you need to compile with the 1.4 compatibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

49.0 is Java 1.5, so it sounds like your server is expecting Java 1.4.

Comment: So if I recompile the jar files using Java 1.4 it should be ok? Its my first java project so I had no idea that it required a certain version. 

Is it the JDK I compile with or the JVM that Eclipse uses to save the edited class file?

The server support people have said: 

Server is running with latest Java support version which is 6.0.150

Does this make sense?

Comment: 6.0.150 is probably the version of the server, not the version of Java.  Compile your code with Java 1.4, or with "1.4 compatibility", which is an option of javac as well as an option in Eclipse.

Comment: @Shaun, in Eclipse's Project Properties, under Java Compiler, set Compiler compliance level to 1.4. And your server support people appear to be either mistaken or lying. You could try using a simple class to display `System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")`

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Paul, @Peter, I shall try recompiling and testing again

Comment: Ok, so Ive found that my live server is using jvm 1.4:

http://www.mccran.co.uk/examples/qr-generator/test.cfm

It doesn't look like the code from Google will run on a 1.4 environment (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes) (setup header) so I'm scuppered.

Comment: Can you get your hosting company to upgrade to a recent version of Java?  Generally 99.99% of code that was compiled for Java 1.4 will continue to work with Java 5 or Java 6, so it shouldn't break anything.

Comment: @Shaun, have you tried recompiling the library under 1.4 and using it? I don't think I still have any copies of rt.jar from 1.4 around to check dependencies, but the language changes from 1.4 to 1.5 aren't so major that you couldn't manually fix any compilation errors they cause.